# How to find total working hours by each employee from their start date in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

A company record its employees movement In and Out of office in a table with 3 columns
`(Employee id, Action (In/Out), Created)`.

First entry for each employee is “In”.
Every “In” is succeeded by an “Out". No data gaps and, employee can work across days.

```
Employee id  Action  Created
1             In    2019-04-01 12:00:00
1             Out   2019-04-01 15:00:00
1             In    2019-04-01 17:00:00
1             Out   2019-04-01 21:00:00
```

Question is to Measure amount of hours spent by each employee inside the office since the day they started (Account for current  shift if she/he is working). Can you help in solving this ?

Comment: what is the version of your MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one of the simplest approaches is the difference in row numbers methods.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, which has support for analytic functions, here is one way to do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, Action
                                 ORDER BY Created) rn
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT EmployeeId, rn,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'In' THEN Created END),
            MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Out' THEN Created END)) AS num_hours
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY EmployeeId, rn
)

SELECT EmployeeId, SUM(num_hours) AS total_num_hours
FROM cte2
GROUP BY EmployeeId;
```

### Demo

The approach here first computes the number of hours spent within each in/out interval pair, for each employee.  It then does a second aggregation by employee to get the totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and then aggregate:

```
select employeeid,
       sum(timestampdiff(hour, created, next_created) as num_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(created) over (partition by employeeid order by created) as next_created
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'In'
group by employeeid;
```

I would caution you that this assumes that the "in"s and "out"s are perfectly alternating.  And that would be unlikely to be true with real-world data.

If this is not true for your data, you should accept one of the answers here and ask a *new* question with better sample data and more explanation on how to handle the anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

with a as (select employee_id as e1,actions as a1,created as c1, row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by created)
row_num1
from trial12 where actions='in'),b as  (select employee_id e2,actions a2,created c2, row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by created)
row_num2
from trial12 where actions='out') select e1 , sum(datediff(hour,cast(c1 as datetime),cast(c2 as datetime))) from a,b where row_num1 = row_num2
group by e1

Comment: Please use Syntaxhighlighting to make it easier to read